# Hypernym for "pros" and "cons"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Is there a single word to denote *pros and cons*? For example,

> Here you can view the [pros and cons] of this product.

*update:*
When reading the word, one should immediately understand that it's about the *pros and cons* and not features/specifications in general. Think about a block or section, with 2 lists, a *pros* list and *cons* list. It's that block or section I want to refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can view the [**criteria**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/criteria) of this product.

> [**criterion**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criterion): a characterizing mark or trait

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is technically called a "hypernym" - that is, a word which represents a wider concept than the word you've started with. You're looking for a word that is a hypernym for both "pro" and "con". [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn) provides the ability to look up hypernyms for words, and it suggests **arguments** or **statements**.

You might also consider **considerations**, **aspects**, **factors**, or even **circumstances** though none of them quite convey what you want.

Overall, although no single word answer seems to beat the original phrase **pros and cons**, I think I like **considerations** the best:

> Here you can view the **considerations** for this product

Or simply:

> Product **considerations**

Answer (score 0):

Features would work perfectly in your example:

> Here you can view the **features** of this product.

[fea·ture](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/feature)  [fee-cher]

> noun
>
> 1. a prominent or conspicuous part or characteristic: Tall buildings were a new feature on the skyline.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I was looking for. When reading the word, one should immediately understand that it's about the _pros and cons_ and not features/specifications in general.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the word **Trade-offs**

Comment: Please consider posting a reference and a definition.

Answer (score 0):

"merits" (plural) would better work for your section header. While its predominant meaning is positive characteristics, it has legal and historical senses that may refer to either positive or negative ones.

Wiktionary defines the legal sense with an extended use: "(by extension) the overall good or bad quality, or rightness or wrongness, of some other thing."

The previous answers correctly identified the need for a hypernym, but provided ones too broad for your section header.

Other languages, like English, juxtapose pro and con in their phrases for this use; I could find no other satisfactory germanic equivalent.

Words of ambiguous connotation like "exploit",  which can mean a heroic deed or the taking advantage of a vulnerability, could be used, though these are too strong for your use.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're right. I have removed the neologisms accordingly.